# is it possible for Canny Edge to measure?

Tags: c#, winforms, emgucv

Hi sirs I'm just wondering if is it possible for me to measure the height or width of an object using canny edge?

and if there's other way?

Comment: Can you provide more information?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, and yes there are other ways.

Comment: sir @meilke my project is about uniform fitting it gives the standard sizes of polo/blouse like Small, Medium, Large ,etc. so I was wondering if I can use canny edge pictures as a way to measure the end of the left shoulder to the end of the right shoulder...

Comment: sir @BartoszKP what other ways would that be? and what would be the best way? :)

Comment: @codename_newbie The simplest way I can think of is region growth segmentation, and then measuring the segments. There are likely many other segmentation methods. You've provided to little details in your question to make any discussion possible. And, it's off-topic on SO by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @BartoszKP correctly stated, there are numerous ways on how to solve your problem. If, however, you want to go ahead and solve it with the help of the Canny edge detection you could do something like this:

1. Create Canny edge image
2. Do [Hough line detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform) ([here is an example in Emgu](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Shape_%28Triangle,_Rectangle,_Circle,_Line%29_Detection_in_CSharp)) to get geometrical information on where the lines in your image are - they might now represent your clothing article outline in a much more usable way
3. Use the geometrical information to rule out the non-shoulder lines - normally you should have all the information you need on all the lines (like where they are exactly in the image). That information might just enable you  to throw away, let's say, the bottom end of the clothing article.
4. Use the geometrical information of the remaining lines to calculate your shoulder width or whatever you want to calculate.

Comment: from the canny edge image how? what? step should I take next for me to detect the edge of the shoulder...

i'm really sorry sir this is my first project using emgu...

Comment: Adjusted the answer. Better now?

Comment: thank you sir I'll start working on it I just hope I can do this

Comment: Can you see the e-mail on my account? If so let me know how it's working out and if you got more questions.

Comment: from the sample you've given sir I think I can make the hough line...

but how will I do 3 and 4? :D

Comment: The resulting line objcts should have enough information (see my edited answer) on where they are exactly in the image. That might just enable you to get what you want. Try drawing them into an example image and you will know what I mean.

Comment: sir I've finished detecting lines how will I teach the program to measure the distance between my left shoulder to my right shoulder...

I don't understand the thing about geometrical information to rule out the non shoulder lines? what will I do?

sorry I'm too dumb with math and english

Comment: How many lines do you get? Do you get the shoulder lines? Is there anything in the line information that might rule out the other lines? Like orientation, position etc. In the end you want to end up with only two lines or so or with only two corners.

Comment: hmm how can I tell how many lines? I'm getting the whole body? 
here's a pic?
[link](http://tinypic.com/r/2v2jcqe/5)

Comment: Now it's getting tough. If you allow any image showing clothing articles on people under a lot of circumstances, you will have a lot of problems. But you might look for lines with an orientation of around 135 degrees in the top-left corner (and 45 degrees in the top-right corner). Throw away the rest and there you go. But again, this looks like a tough cookie.

Comment: hmm? are we just going to focus on the shoulders only? or its just for now? the project will get whole body measurement :(

Width of the shoulders,waistline, length of inner and outer legs? @_@

hmm will it still be feasible?

Comment: sir @meike hmm can I do something like this?
[link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IbmnD_u1xuQ)